# Should we ask questions to "rubber duck" the solution?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I don't know how many of you have experienced the [Rubber Duck](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubberDucking) principle when posting questions on SO, but I know I have on a few occasions. And then I just discard my question. So here's the question:

**Should we go ahead and post the question?**

Of course if it's something stupid like forgetting a semicolon, etc., I would say no... but there are several occasions, like if a data structure doesn't make sense, that at least someone would eventually benefit from the question/answers.

And if you *should* ask the question, how would you recommend choosing an answer for it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I think you should go ahead and post the question, with one caveat.  It needs to be searchable.  Most rubber duck questions that I've started (and not posted) are usually titled "Why doesn't this work?"  That isn't very informative.  If you can write a good title for it, then post it.

We've already established that it's encouraged to answer your own question.  The system forces you to let it mix with the community's answers for a while before you can accept it.

Comment: I think that's an excellent caveat. I have posted at least one question that I intended to self-answer, and the unexpected happened - rather than accepting my own (fairly well thought answer), I ended out accepting another answer that ended out better than mine. But the title was certainly much more descriptive than "Why doesn't this work?" ;)