# What should be done with questions that typing it up helps me to solve the question?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

If I start writing up a question, and the very process of organizing my thoughts into a form appropriate for StackOverflow causes me to figure out the answer on my own, what is the appropriate thing? (Assuming the answer is more complicated than a syntax error or "I wrote `>` when it should have been `>=` etc.)

1. Delete whatever I have of the question draft
2. Convert the question into "answer your own question, Q&A style"
3. It depends on whether me figuring it out was because I got better organized or because I saw a suggested question that answered my question (and thus I would be posting a duplicate)?
4. It depends on my confidence level in the solution I figured out on my own
5. Other

Comment: Really depends. Is it a simple error that you can find easily, like a syntax error? If so, probably don't post it. If it's something difficult to find... possibly a good question to post your own answer to.

Comment: @hichris123: edited in response

Comment: Related: [Rubber ducking](http://www.c2.com/cgi/wiki?RubberDucking) (and [duplicate Meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/60552/223030))